# How to validate credential in MVC and redirect to bad login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authentication

I want to centralize authentication that developers are free to worry about the implementation of security.

I dont want to validate the authentication at each request like

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{    
    public ActionResult Home()    
    {        
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated == true)        
        {            
            return RedirectToAction("Home", "Member");        
        }        
        return View();    
    }    

    public ActionResult Resources()    
    {        
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated == true)        
        {            
            return RedirectToAction("Resources", "Member");        
        }        
        return View();    
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can centralized your credential validation by using a BaseController for all your controller inside your application

```
public class BaseSupplierFlyersController : BaseController
  {
    //
    // GET: /SupplierFlyers/
    public ActionResult Index(string culture)
    {
      //Some action logic here
      return View("Index");
    }
}
```

In your BaseControler

```
public class BaseController : Controller
  {
    private bool IsLoged = false;
    public BaseController()
      : base()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      if (!IsLoged)
      {
        //Redirection du bad login.
        //Affect the Result to cancelled previous Action execution
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(string.Concat("~/", ControllerConstants.Error,"/", ActionConstants.BadLogin));
      }
      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    protected override void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
      //Validate Credential
      ValidateCredential(requestContext);
      //Traitement standard
      base.Execute(requestContext);
    }

    private void ValidateCredential(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
      //Logic to validate credential here
      IsLoged = true; //or false
    }
  }
```

Each time an Action from a Controller is fired the BaseController will validate credential in Execute method and in OnActionExecuting you can valide if the credential are valid and than take an Action like Redirect to an other page.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you wrote it seems like you are missing Action Filters that are part of asp.net mvc. There is one built in called `Authorize` that basically requires a request to be authenticated before the controller method is invoked, but creating your own is very simple.

Also in asp.net mvc 3 you can define global filters which will be part of every action invoked on your controllers. You can find some samples [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs)